# How to convert a character to a numeric data type in R

Tags: r

I have a big .csv file and one of the columns "ride_id" is a character type. I would like to convert it to numeric type but I get NA values.

```
ride_id        
<chr>       
3ED2B8BCE6A914EF    
7359345F8EB21CDC        
A62608C1D9DF9360        
20D609100DF8A71C    
6DF34F98F5DB335F    
E3194C33D112E064
```

I try using this code and it doesnt work:

```
ride_id = as.numeric(ride_id)
```

The reason I would like to convert the data type is to calculate the total into a separate column. This would then be used as a y variable in a geom_line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show your expected output.  the column is character.  If you want to extract some numeric part, it should be different way

Comment: Are you looking for `as.numeric(factor(ride_id))` ?

Comment: I note the character strings are all in hexadecimal digits, so conceivably they could represent 64 bit integers - so `eval(parse(text = paste0("c(", paste0("0x", ride_id, collapse = ", "), ")")))` converts them (approximately) into the numbers they represent, but my guess is you are just looking for a unique numerical label for each - `as.numeric(factor(ride_id))`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possibilities.

**1) type.convert**

```
transform(ride_id, num = type.convert(paste0("0x", chr), as.is = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
               chr          num
1 3ED2B8BCE6A914EF 4.526884e+18
2 7359345F8EB21CDC 8.311732e+18
3 A62608C1D9DF9360 1.197227e+19
4 20D609100DF8A71C 2.366089e+18
5 6DF34F98F5DB335F 7.922764e+18
6 E3194C33D112E064 1.636419e+19
```

**2) strotoi**  Break the character string up into 4 strings of 4 characters each, convert those using `strtoi` (which can only work on sufficiently short strings) and then matrix multiply that by the indicated vector.

```
transform(ride_id, num = chr |>
  textConnection() |>
  read.fwf(c(4, 4, 4, 4)) |>
  apply(2, strtoi, base = 16) |>
  t() |>
  crossprod(cbind((16^4)^(3:0))))
```

giving:

```
               chr          num
1 3ED2B8BCE6A914EF 4.526884e+18
2 7359345F8EB21CDC 8.311732e+18
3 A62608C1D9DF9360 1.197227e+19
4 20D609100DF8A71C 2.366089e+18
5 6DF34F98F5DB335F 7.922764e+18
6 E3194C33D112E064 1.636419e+19
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "chr
3ED2B8BCE6A914EF
7359345F8EB21CDC
A62608C1D9DF9360
20D609100DF8A71C
6DF34F98F5DB335F
E3194C33D112E064"
ride_id <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm not convinced the OP is looking for the unsigned 64-bit integers these strings could represent, though that's unclear from the question. It's perhaps worth pointing out that the results here are imprecise due to conversion to double precision floats (hex often implies an exact integer), and R can't natively store integers this large. Nice to find out about `type.convert` though.